# C# error when a table has an empty record

Tags: c#, sql, database

When i run my application i get an error that not all the fields of the table `tblContact` are filled. How do i edit in my code that if a record is `null` I show in my application null.

Here is my code:

```
 public void SelID(int Zoek)
        {
            string SQL = "select * from tblContact";
            SQL += " where cNr=" + Zoek.ToString();
            DataTable DT = Database.ExecSelect(SQL);
            if (DT.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                pr_cNr = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                pr_cNr = (int)(DT.Rows[0]["cNr"]);
                pr_cVNaam = (string)(DT.Rows[0]["cVnaam"]);
                pr_cTNaam = (string)(DT.Rows[0]["cTNaam"]);
                pr_cANaam = (string)(DT.Rows[0]["cAnaam"]);
                pr_cAdres = (string)(DT.Rows[0]["cAdres"]);
                pr_cPost = (string)(DT.Rows[0]["cPost"]);
                pr_cPlaats = (string)(DT.Rows[0]["cPlaats"]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Side note: sql *hardcoding*: `" where cNr=" + Zoek.ToString();` is a *bad practice*; use parameters instead.

Answer (score 3):

try this way:

```
object val = row["ColumnName"];
if (val == DBNull.Value)
    // your code
else
    //your code
```

using inline checking for all columns makes your code messy and error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you have to check for `null`:

```
...         
else
{
    // In case of integer we have to specify how null should be treated:
    pr_cNr = DT.Rows[0].IsNUll("cNr") 
       ? -1                                  // or whatever default value
       : Convert.ToInt32(DT.Rows[0]["cNr"]);

    // In case of string Convert.ToString(DBNull.Value) returns empty string "" 
    // Please, notice that original (string) (DBNull.Value) throws exception
    pr_cVNaam  = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[0]["cVnaam"]);
    pr_cTNaam  = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[0]["cTNaam"]);
    pr_cANaam  = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[0]["cAnaam"]);
    pr_cAdres  = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[0]["cAdres"]);
    pr_cPost   = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[0]["cPost"]);
    pr_cPlaats = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[0]["cPlaats"]);
}
```

Comment: @Jari PSV: in case of `string`, `Convert.ToString(DBNull.Value)` returns *empty string* `""`, but you can specufy a default: `pr_cVNaam  =   DT.Rows[0].IsNull("cVnaam") ? "MyDefault" : Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[0]["cVnaam"]);`